# Semilinear equation (PDE)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, elliptic-equations

I've found this hard exercise on chapter 6 of Evans' book. I have no idea on how to proceed.

Assume $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has compact support, and assume that it is a weak solution of the semi linear equation
$$
-\Delta u+c(u)=f\;\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{R^n}
$$
where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function with $c(0)=0$ and $c'\ge 0$. Prove that $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R^n})$.

Any hints?

Comment: I don't know which version you have, but my version has the hint that: Mimic the proof of Theorem 1 in 6.3.1, but without the cutoff function $\xi$. I did this problem myself before and it can be solved by this hint, just some calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying by a test function $v$ and using the divergence theorem we obtain: 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}(f-c(u))v\,dx$$ let $v=-\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta_j^h u$ for some direction $j\in\{1,...,d\}$,

where $\Delta^h_ju=\frac{u(x+he_j)-u(x)}{h}$

then 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla u\cdot\nabla (-\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta_j^h u)\,dx=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}(f-c(u))\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta^h_ju\,dx$$ now 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla u\cdot\nabla (-\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta_j^h u)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\Delta^h_j\nabla u\cdot\nabla (\Delta_j^h u)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\nabla\Delta^h_j u|^2$$ so 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\nabla\Delta^h_j u|^2=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}(f-c(u))\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta^h_ju\,dx$$

$$\le\|f\|_2\|\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta^h_ju\|_2+\|\Delta^h_jc(u)\|_2\|\Delta^h_ju\|_2$$
$$\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|f\|_2^2+\epsilon\|\Delta^{-h}_j\Delta^h_ju\|_2^2+\|\nabla c(u)\|_2\|\nabla u\|_2$$
$$\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|f\|_2^2+\epsilon\|\nabla\Delta^h_ju\|_2^2+\|\nabla c(u)\|_2\|\nabla u\|_2$$ thus 
$$\|\Delta^h_j D_k u\|_2\le\|\Delta^h_j\nabla u\|_2\le(\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|f\|_2^2+\|\nabla c(u)\|_2\|\nabla u\|_2])^{\frac{1}{2}}\lt\infty$$ for any direction $k\in\{1,...,d\}$.
Moreover the final bound is uniform, and therefore $\|D_jD_ku\|\lt\infty$ for any directions $j,k\in\{1,...,d\}$, and since already $u\in H^1(\mathbb R^d)$, it follows that $u\in H^2(\mathbb R^d)$